# Package imported into Node.js TypeScript file not recognized by namespace section declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm, javascript-namespaces

I am using JetBrain's WebStorm IDE to edit a TypeScript file as part of a Node.js **v8.6.0** project.  I have the JavaScript version for the project set to **JSX Harmony**.  At the top of the TypeScript source file is an import statement that aliases the package to the label **signer**:

```
import {Signer as signer} from '../lib/rds/signer';
```

However, WebStorm's syntax highlighter marks the import as *unused*.  This is despite the fact the alias is used in the following *namespace* section, later on in the same TypeScript file:

```
declare namespace RDS {
  export import Signer = signer;
}
```

Worse, the *export-import* line is marked with an error indicating that **signer** is considered an *unresolved symbol*.

How can I resolve this issue so that WebStorm recognizes **signer** as a valid value for the *export-import* declaration, and that subsequently the *Signer* package import is *not* unused?

Comment: Are both of the lines posted by you in the same file? The export import syntax doesn't look like a valid JS/TS syntax.

Comment: @Cristy Yes.  The exact same Typescript file (*.ts).

Comment: Where did you see the docs for the `export import Name = value` syntax?

Comment: import {signer} from '../lib/rds/signer'; or 
import signer from '../lib/rds/signer';

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in both **2017.2.5** and **2017.3 EAP**:

[image]

Please try invalidating caches (`File | Invalidate caches`, `Invalidate and restart`) - does it fix the issue?